# Can robocopy use multiple /SD (source directory) parameters?

Tags: windows, robocopy

I'm creating a `robocopy` job file for users to back up their local data to a network share. I want to give them the option of not just backing up their user data, but application configuraiton files that might be in other places on the drive. When I add an additional `/SD` line, e.g.

```
/SD:C:\PATH\TO\FIRST\DIR\
/SD:C:\PATH\TO\SECOND\DIR\
```

I get an error

```
ERROR : Invalid Job File, Line #12 :"/SD:C:\PATH\TO\SECOND\DIR\"
```

The obvious answer is that robocopy can only support one `/SD` parameter per execution. Is there a way to allow for multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make multiple lines of robocopy

Therefore, you would need to create separate Robocopy commands for each source directory you want to include in the backup job.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not supported by robocopy. You can run multiple instances sequentially or in parallel, however.